# Finding a new job without using vacation days for interviews?

Tags: interviewing, vacation

**Background**

I am currently in the last year of my traineeship.  I am currently working in europe but I came from asia. So my family is far away from me. Last time I saw them was last summer.

**Problem**

I have about 15 vacation days this year. I can use them in two ways. I can either go back to my country or I can stay here and use them whenever I have an interview. If I don't find a job by the end of my traineeship, I will have to return back which I don't want.

I asked my supervisor to allow me to work from home like once a week. He did not allow me. He is quite inflexible.

What should I do?

1. Use 12 vacation days to go home and keep 2 or 3 days for an interview
2. Stay here and use all my days for interviewing(Cause I am terrible at interviews and I am sure I wont find a job till like the 12th one)
3. Another way?

**More Generally**

How to find a new job, without using your vacation days, when you have an inflexible supervisor ?

Comment: Is your current job planned to end at the end of your traineeship? If so, you can take this issue up directly with your supervisor, without hiding your plan to go to interviews.

Comment: Yes my job will end at the end of my traineeship. Actually He says that if you want to interview then you should use your vacation days.

Comment: Am I correct in reading that your intent for "work from home" is not to actually work but to interview elsewhere?

Comment: @MichaelT Well my intent was to have a lot of flexibility for interviews since I can work on saturdays and sundays but I cant interview on these days. Ofcourse, I was going to report my progress weekly to him.

Comment: Is days off without pay an option?

Comment: @Kai Could be an option but then again I might not get the certificate at the end of my traineeship and I will lose a lo of money.

Comment: If you don't find another job, you have to go home anyways.  Seems like the priority is obvious.  Plus, if you do find another job, your vacation days reset, then you can see your family.

Comment: "Cause I am terrible at interviews and I am sure I wont find a job till like the 12th one" -- that's not that unusual.  At least in my industry (software dev) there are a large number of employers who aren't actually serious about hiring but are more than willing to waste your time on a long, drawn out interview process that ultimately ends with them hiring no one and then cancelling or re-posting the position.  You usually have to interview for a while to learn what flags to look for to weed these idiots out early.

Comment: @JamesAdam What is your recommendation for my question ?

Comment: @TuUML - Nothing really, other than I'd suggest that you be selective about who you choose to interview with (You are investing your time, after all). It feels weird (maybe even *wrong*) to turn down and interview the first time you do it, but if you're currently employed you can afford to say "no" if you get a negative vibe from an employer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to work out what's more important to you: finding a job in Europe or seeing your family. Once you've done that, the decision is easy.

Two possibly related points:

1. Maybe you'll get a job after your first couple of interviews; problem solved.
2. If you do use all your vacation days interviewing but do manage to find a job, you could always take a couple of weeks off between the end of your traineeship and the new job. No (good) employer is going to look down on you for "I haven't seen my family for a year, so I'm going back to visit for a couple of weeks" if they ask why you want some time off.

Comment: I dont want a delay between two jobs because it will end my chances of getting a permanent residency.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you look for a job after your traineeship: you use your vacation days to find a job, and then go home after your traineeship finishes.

Comment: ... and then come back to start the job that you've already secured.

Answer (score 0):

Or ask your current boss if you can take some unpaid days for personal business, since the trip home burned most of your vacation. You usually  don't have to day what kind of personal business, as long as everyone agrees they can spare you for that day.

"The object of the game is to be as honest as the law allows."